# Pythonic way to add a list of vectors

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a method (sum) that takes a variable number of vectors and adds them in. For educational purposes, I have written my own `Vector` class, and the underlying data is stored in an instance variable named data.

My code for the `@classmethod` sum works (for each of the vectors passed in, loop through each element in the data variable and add it to a result list), but it seems non-Pythonic, and wondering if there is a better way?

```
class Vector(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    @classmethod
    def sum(cls, *args):
        result = [0 for _ in range(len(args[0].data))]
        for v in args:
            if len(v.data) != len(result): raise
            for i, element in enumerate(v.data):
                result[i] += element

        return cls(result)
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I was thinking that sum should return a new vector, and thus used a class method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**`itertools.izip_longest`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) may come very handy in your situation:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
c = [1, 2]

lists = (a, b, c)

result = [sum(el) for el in itertools.izip_longest(*lists, fillvalue=0)]
```

And here you got what you wanted:

```
>>> result
[3, 6, 6, 8, 5, 6]
```

What it does is simply zips up your lists together, by filling empty value with `0`. e.g. `izip_longest(a, b)` would be `[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 0), (4, 0)]`. Then just sums up all the values in each tuple element of the intermediate list.

So here you go step by step:

```
>>> lists
([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2])
>>> list(itertools.izip_longest(*lists, fillvalue=0))
[(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 0), (4, 4, 0), (0, 5, 0), (0, 6, 0)]
```

So if you run a list comprehension, summing up all sub-elements, you get your result.

Answer (score 5):

Another thing that you could do (and that might be more "pythonic") would be to implement the [`__add__` magic method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types), so you can use `+` and `sum` directly on vectors.

```
class Vector(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Vector):
            return Vector([s + o for s, o in zip(self.data, other.data)])
        if isinstance(other, int):
            return Vector([s + other for s in self.data])
        raise TypeError("can not add %s to vector" % other)

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self.__add__(other)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Vector(%r)" % self.data
```

Here, I also implemented addition of `Vector` and `int`, adding the number on each of the Vector's data elements, and the "reverse addition" `__radd__`, to make `sum` work properly.

Example:

```
>>> v1 = Vector([1,2,3])
>>> v2 = Vector([4,5,6])
>>> v3 = Vector([7,8,9])
>>> v1 + v2 + v3
Vector([12, 15, 18])
>>> sum([v1,v2,v3])
Vector([12, 15, 18])
```

Comment: Thank you for this, and I didn't consider this approach and learned something new!

Answer (score 2):

```
args = [[1,   2,  3],
        [10, 20, 30],
        [7,   3, 15]]

result = [sum(data) for data in zip(*args)]
# [18, 25, 48]
```

Is this what you want?